# How do I force Visual Studio 2008 to use an Open instance when double clicking a file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Certain non-project files that I use Visual studio for (.build, .xml, free-roaming html and css files) are already associated with visual studio and open in it when i double click them.

How can I get them to open in an existing instance of visual studio?   Right now If i double-click the same file twice, it will open two instances of visual studio, I'd like it just to basically ignore the second open attempt if there is already an instance of VS open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok Richard helped point me in the right direction a bit, but I think I found exactly what I want.

1. from an explorer window, go to Tools->Folder Options->File Types tab
2. find the extension you wish to change.
3. If there is a restore button click it.
4. Click Advanced
5. Click New... to create a new action.
6. I set the following:

Action: Open in VS 2008
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /dde
check use dde
DDE Message:  Open("%1")
Application: VisualStudio.9.0
DDE Application Not Running: (left blank)
Topic: System

7. Hit Ok
8. Set the new action as the default.
9. Hit Ok, Hit Ok

Now that extension will behave exactly as described in the question.  The file will open in an existing VS if visual studio is already open.

I also used this to fix a few extensions that got broken when I reinstalled VS 2005 after 2008.

Win 7/ VS 2012
You can right click a file, go to properties.
Then there is an "Opens With" line and a change button. But I don't see a way to force other command line options.   VS2012 seems to use the open instance by default.

Comment: The FileTypes tab no longer exists fro Server 2008 and Vista/Win7 (and I'm assuming Win8). Any pointers?

Comment: This question was specific to VS2008 and i'm not sure if thats the visual studio you are still trying to open but I added a little bit about win7 anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find the options, either. so it goes!

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 vs2010 answer;

Because "Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program" is so useless, use regedit.

Navigate to **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.XXX.10.0\shell\Open\Command** and add **/edit** to the end of the open with line, where XXX is the filetype you wish to affect.

Example .reg file for .cpp;

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.cpp.10.0\shell\Open\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\\Common7\\IDE\\devenv.exe\" /dde /edit"
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of VS?

For 2003, there's [VSEdit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSEdit).

In 2005, well, that's the way it works for me out-of-the-box.  A quick Google search found [something](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2005/12/08/501824.aspx) that may help.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Visual Studio also seem to have problems opening files via DDE from certain applications (e.g. in SSHCommunications' Secure File Transfer Client; Winzip and explorer seem to work fine). This still happens with the solutions given previously.

1. When IDE already loaded, the IDE focuses but gives error 'The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct'
2. When IDE not loaded, it intermittently gives error 'The file cannot be opened because it is being used by another process. Please close all applications that might access this file and try again'. Trying again proceeds as 1)

You can get it working in all situations using a combination of all the previous posts!

1. Install the [VSEdit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VSEdit) application (as suggested by Richard/Jeff for .Net 2003), regardless of the version (or versions) of msdev that you use: the [post](http://saraford.net/2005/12/08/use-devenv-edit-to-open-any-file-in-an-existing-visual-studio-instance-vsedit-functionality/) by Sara Ford to which they refer recommends VSEdit for command line operation in VS2005 - it also seems to work for later versions.
2. Alter the DDE (Tools->Folder Options->File Types) as Jeff proposes but to open via VSEdit.exe instead of devenv.exe directly. Specifically:

> Action: Open "C:\Program Files\PowerToys for Visual Studio .NET
>   2003\VSEdit\VSEdit.exe" /c  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /Edit """%1"""" "%1" use dde: (checked) DDE  Message: (left blank)  Application: VSEdit DDE Application Not
>   Running: (left blank)  Topic: System

N.B. The triple/quad quotation marks are deliberate - they add the first opened file (quoted) to the end of the launch command to prevent msdev complaining about the command line usage of the /Edit mode if launched. Obviously command paths will need changing for different installations.